# Embedding elements of Facebook into website

Tags: facebook, web, embed

I would like to do a couple of things with my website that would intergrate elements of Facebook.

The first is to embed my status (from a Facebook Fan Page) to my website
The second is to embed events that I've created on Facebook into my website and if possible allow users to RSVP instantly.

I know some basic html so all the help and any help would be great.

Thank You

Comment: Have you looked at http://developers.facebook.com/?

Answer (score 1):

try googling for the `facebook social plugins` where they give you plugin codes that you can insert in your site [plain html scripts] so that you get your facebook status etc..

may be you can check this 
`http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/`